# Who was this awkwardly excited girl at the wedding in Supergirl S03E08?

Tags: character, arrowverse, the-flash, supergirl

During the Arrowverse crossover in *Supergirl S03E08*, there was one girl who met Barry on his wedding but behaved way too awkwardly:

[image][image]

She said she was excited for the wedding and then corrected herself and said "any wedding". I don't remember her mentioning her name but her reply to Barry was suspicious.

Is this a hint of some important future character? Did she appear before this scene too?

I mean it looks like a important hint for the future but what is it?

Comment: It's gotta be Barry and Iris's daughter from a future timeline. The actress looks the part, anyway. So a seed for a future plot.

Comment: Actress is Jessica Parker Kennedy, and as mentioned above I see some online speculation that she's Barry's daughter from the future. She returned in The Flash as well. Doesn't look like anything's confirmed yet.

Comment: There is a name for this and it was in a question on here recently but I can't remember what it's called. It's the phenomena of the audience realising a seemingly insignificant character will be significant later by virtue of the fact they are played by a significant actor. [EDIT] Found it: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83110/is-there-a-term-meaning-a-character-whom-you-know-cant-be-a-minor-character-be

Comment: @Kitkat ahhh, I knew she looked familiar. Big fan of Black Sails. One thing about Vancouver shows is the acting pool is small so even bit part roles may get filled by someone who was "big" in another show.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

***Season 4 Finale Update**

The girl has revealed herself to be **Nora West-Allen**, the daughter of Barry & Iris although whether she follows the same story-line history as the comic version remains to be seen.

---

## We don't know <sup>(as of pre-S4 finale)</sup>, but...

Assuming this is *intended* to be significant <sup>*</sup> there are a couple of likely possibilities...

<sup>* - Which is likely since [**Jessica Parker Kennedy**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2498781/) (who played the waiter/caterer) also appears in the season 4 *"The Elongated Man Rises"* episode and is writing in the same symbols as Barry used when he returned from the Speed Force.</sup>

[image][image]

### Dawn Allen*

> Dawn Allen was the daughter of Barry and Iris Allen, conceived in the 30th Century after her father's retirement, but born after his death in the first Crisis. She and her twin brother Don inherited a fraction of his speed. Since they never knew their father, they often felt jealous of their cousin Wally West, to whom Barry was a father figure.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Dawn_Allen_(New_Earth))</sup>

### Jenni Ognats (XS)

> XS is a speedster and superhero in the 30th Century. She is a member of the Legion of Super-Heroes representing Earthgov in Reboot Legion continuity. Her grandfather is Barry Allen, also known as The Flash, which makes her part of the Flash Family. Her mother is Dawn Allen of the Tornado Twins, her father is the politician Jeven Ognats, and her cousin is Bart Allen.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Jenni_Ognats)</sup>

Comment: It is very appropriate that the role Jessica Parker Kennedy plays in between the two episodes is in a film called "Someone Else's Wedding"!

Comment: Good catch with her being in the background! Over on *Arrow*, [Carrie Cutter (a.k.a. Cupid)](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Carrie_Cutter) also appeared in several background scenes before being introduced on the show. It was revealed that she was "stalking" the Green Arrow before meeting him face to face. So this person appearing in the background is definitely significant, and not just a case of being too lazy to cast extras.

Comment: That edit kind of helped only

Answer (score 5):

We now know that she is the **daughter of Barry Allen and Iris West-Allen** and her name is **Nora West-Allen**. She is named after her deceased grandmother Nora Allen who was killed by Reverse Flash. She is also a speedster and goes by the alias **XS**. She has both purple and yellow lightning showing characteristics of both her mother and father. Her name is different from the comics based daughter of Barry and Iris i.e. Dawn Allen. Dawn Allen is the twin sister of Don Allen and they together are known as *Tornado Twins*. We do not know anything about Don Allen till now in the TV series and also we do not know about the Date of Birth of Nora West-Allen.

Comment: **Dawn** is also the daughter of Barry and Iris in the TV show, but in the original timeline **only** (The one where Eobard Thawne comes from and where Barry's mother has not been murdered).